# int is changing back to initial state unexpectedly

Tags: c

I have used a debugger on this code and there is a spot in my code where an int changes unexpectedly.  I declare int jpg = 0 near the top.  About 10 lines below that I increment jpg by 1.  The debugger says jpg = 1 at this point. It makes it to the next line, if jpg < 10.  Then something weird happens.  After the sprintf function takes place, jpg now equals 0.  Why??!!  It's screwing up the rest of my code.  I can't figure out why it is changing jpg back to 0 right here.

Thanks for your help, Todd

---

```
FILE *outptr;

int main(void)
{
    // open input file 
    FILE* image = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open, does %s exist?\n", "card.raw");
        return 1;
    }

    // declare a pointer to buffer
    BYTE buffer[512];

    // count the number of JPG files and create JPG filename
    int jpg = 0;
    char filename[7];

    // read 512 bytes of the card
    while (fread(&buffer, 1, 512, image) == 512)
    {
        // check first 4 bytes for JPG header info
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
        {
            // increment jpg number and jpg filename
            jpg = jpg + 1;

            if (jpg < 10)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "00%d.jpg", jpg);
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(filename, "0%d.jpg", jpg);
            } 

            // check if this is first JPG, close previous jpg file if not

            if (jpg != 1)
            {
                fclose(outptr);
            }

            // open output file
            FILE* outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fclose(image);
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", filename);
                return 2;
            }

            // write the 512B of buffer info to JPG file
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, 512, outptr);
        } 

        // not the start of a new jpg file, have we reached a jpg yet? 
        else if (jpg != 0)
        {
            // write the 512B of buffer info to JPG file
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, 512, outptr);
        }      
    }

    // close the files
    fclose(image);
    fclose(outptr);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to open the "raw" file in *text mode*?

Comment: The `outptr` shadows the global declaration. I'm not sure if this causes the problem (rather unlikely IMO) but that looks like UB (`fclose` needs a non-null pointer, I believe).

Comment: `filename` is not large enough to hold the output of `sprintf`. You have a 7 character string plus the NUL. It's overflowing and overwriting `jpg`

Comment: As a general point, it is better to store and test the result with `bytesread=fread(...)`, because the final block might not fill the buffer. Then on every block you `fwrite(&buffer, 1, bytesread, outptr);`

Answer (score 1):

You have a *buffer overflow*. The `filename` array is missing space for the string terminator so you are writing *eight* characters to a seven-character array. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thank you so much guys!! The filename was not big enough, which fixed that issue.  I was still having an issue when writing to outptr the second time.  It was because I declared FILE* outptr again in the code and overwrote the global variable.  I removed FILE* from the later declaration and everything worked great!  Thanks again!!